# Regridding a rasterbrick in R using bilinear interpolation

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, netcdf

I have a rasterbrick (of monthly precipitation data from 1901 to 2018) and it is currently in a at a resolution of 0.5, 0.5 x,y.

here are the details of the data:

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 59, 52, 3068, 1416  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 12, 38, -46.5, -17  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : C:/Users/teyah/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2ffibl/raster/r_tmp_2020-09-28_145010_7728_36039.grd 
names      : X1901.01.16, X1901.02.15, X1901.03.16, X1901.04.16, X1901.05.16, X1901.06.16, X1901.07.16, X1901.08.16, X1901.09.16, X1901.10.16, X1901.11.16, X1901.12.16, X1902.01.16, X1902.02.15, X1902.03.16, ... 
min values :           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0, ... 
max values :       249.9,       248.9,       223.7,       134.2,       264.1,       184.6,       191.2,       129.4,       268.5,       226.5,       280.0,       257.4,       190.0,       154.5,       237.5, ...
```

I also have a second dataset also of monthly precipitation data from 1850 to 2014 but this one is at a resolution of 1.875, 1.25  x, y.

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 23, 13, 299, 1032  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1.875, 1.25  (x, y)
extent     : 13.125, 37.5, -46.25, -17.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : C:/Users/teyah/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2ffibl/raster/r_tmp_2020-09-28_145148_7728_36431.grd 
names      :  X2015.01.16,  X2015.02.15,  X2015.03.17,  X2015.04.16,  X2015.05.16,  X2015.06.15,  X2015.07.15,  X2015.08.14,  X2015.09.13,  X2015.10.13,  X2015.11.12,  X2015.12.12,  X2016.01.16,  X2016.02.15,  X2016.03.16, ... 
min values : 3.928237e-08, 3.287400e-07, 6.498354e-07, 4.721920e-08, 1.676487e-07, 9.375419e-09, 3.423606e-09, 1.167969e-09, 1.766427e-07, 9.181048e-08, 2.939261e-06, 9.623330e-08, 3.777944e-07, 1.809338e-07, 8.813624e-07, ... 
max values : 1.244237e-04, 1.455906e-04, 1.142002e-04, 7.299686e-05, 4.577329e-05, 3.548095e-05, 8.001707e-05, 7.494183e-05, 1.162102e-04, 2.004935e-04, 1.395226e-04, 1.564750e-04, 1.730213e-04, 2.217189e-04, 1.081660e-04, ...
```

How to I go about converting regridding both of these datasets to a resolution of 1,1 x,y using bilinear interpolation?

Answer (score 1):

Try `aggregate` (in the first case) and `disaggregate` (in the second case) functions from the `raster` package. Note, the argument `fact` in `aggregate` and `disaggregate` can take 2 forms as described in the help page of these functions:

> Aggregation factor expressed as number of cells in each direction (horizontally and vertically). Or two integers (horizontal and vertical aggregation factor) or three integers (when also aggregating over layers).

and

> This can be a single integer or two integers c(x,y), in which case the first one is the horizontal disaggregation factor and y the vertical disaggreation factor. If a single integer value is supplied, cells are disaggregated with the same factor in x and y direction

Assuming that your first raster with `0.5 x 0.5` is called x, then you can do:

```
 aggregate (x, fact = 2)
```

Assuming that your second raster with `1.875 x 1.25` is called y, then you can do:

```
 disaggregate (y, fact = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a reference raster for resampling, this can be done in the terra package. If you have data as a raster object class it can simply be coerced to the terra raster (single or stack) class using `terra::rast` and back again with `raster::stack`.

Add packages and create some data.

```
library(terra)

e <- terra::ext(12, 38, -46.5, -17)

i=59; j=52
r1 <- rast(replicate(10,rast(matrix(runif(i*j), nrow=i, ncol=j))))
  ext(r1) <- e

i=23; j=13
r2 <- rast(replicate(10,rast(matrix(runif(i*j), nrow=i, ncol=j))))
  ext(r2) <- e
```

Use the terra `resample` function to resample the coarse raster to the finer resoultion raster using bilinear.

```
( rs <- terra::resample(r2, r1, method="bilinear") ) 
  par(mfrow=c(2,1))
    plot(r2[[1]])
    plot(rs[[1]])
```